# UltraGrid with Custom Sort

Tags: c#, sorting, ultrawingrid

I have the following code I'd like to be used to custom sort my one column:

```
char[] yourOriginalValues = new [] { '!', 'A', 'B', 'E', '$', 'N' };

IEnumerable<char> result = 
       yourOriginalValues.Where(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            .OrderBy(c => c)
            .Concat(yourOriginalValues.Where(c => !Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)));
```

How would I go about converting this to a custom sort order for WinUltraGrid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See Infragistics forum on this](http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/26894/99295.aspx)

Comment: I've taken a look at that, I'm not entirely sure how to implement what I'd like to accomplish.

Comment: [maybe this link will help](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/NET/2008.3/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v8.3~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~SortComparer.html)

Comment: anvarbek raupov's link no longer works, here's an updated [link](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~SortComparer.html)